# What's this threejs code I'm trying to learn with missing? It won't load

Tags: javascript, three.js, ecma

What's this three.js code I'm trying to learn with missing? It won't load

What's causing it not to load? I'm trying to make it work and the following code came from a couple of online guides on making particle effects work in a THREE.js scene. one of them was actually for a nebula with fog - any ideas?

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Magic Leap MagicScript Test Three JS App</title>
    <style>
      <script>
      <script src="three.min.js"></script>
      </script>
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>

      var scene = cloud;
      .onload: scene;

         let scene, camera, renderer;
         function init() {
           scene = new THREE.Scene();
           camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60,window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,1,1000);
           camera.position.z = 1;
           camera.rotation.x = 1.16;
           camera.rotation.y = -0.12;
           camera.rotation.z = 0.27;
           let ambient = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x555555);
           scene.add(ambient);
           renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
           renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth,window.innerHeight);
           scene.fog = new THREE.FogExp2(0x03544e, 0.001);
           renderer.setClearColor(scene.fog.color);
           document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
           render();
         }
         function render() {
           renderer.render(scene,camera);
           requestAnimationFrame(render);
         }
         init();

         // create the particle variables
       var pMaterial = new THREE.ParticleBasicMaterial({
         color: 0xFFFFFF,
         size: 20,
         map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(
           "https://aerotwist.com/static/tutorials/creating-particles-with-three-js/images/particle.png"
         ),
         blending: THREE.AdditiveBlending,
         transparent: true
       });

       // also update the particle system to
       // sort the particles which enables
       // the behaviour we want
       particleSystem.sortParticles = true;


       // animation loop
       let requestAnimationFrame = TextureEffect

         // add some rotation to the system
         particleSystem.rotation.y += 0.01;

         // draw
         draw.scene, draw.camera
         // set up the next call
         requestAnimFrame(update);

         // set up the next call
         requestAnimationFrame
         requestAnimFrame(update);
       }


       // create a velocity vector
       particle.velocity = new THREE.Vector3(
         0,              // x
         -Math.random(), // y: random vel
         0);             // z

       let loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
      var texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( 'https://cdn.glitch.com/a7c7620f-7b2a-4d7f-b174-747be0295e76%2F2230f846-cecf-43df-8279-3d69109148d0.image.png?v=1586154166108' );

       // immediately use the texture for material creation
       var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture } )
       //the image is known as smoke
      //texture is loaded
       });

       cloudGeo = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(500,500);
       cloudMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
         map:texture,
         transparent: true
       });

       for(let p=0; p<50; p++) {
         let cloud = new THREE.Mesh(cloudGeo, cloudMaterial);
         cloud.position.set(
           Math.random()*800 -400,
           500,
           Math.random()*500-500
         );
         cloud.rotation.x = 1.16;
         cloud.rotation.y = -0.12;
         cloud.rotation.z = Math.random()*2*Math.PI;
         cloud.material.opacity = 0.55;
         cloudParticles.push(cloud);
         scene.add(cloud);
       }

         let cloudParticles = [];

         cloudParticles.push(cloud);

         function render() {
          cloudParticles.forEach(p => {
             p.rotation.z -=0.001;
          });
          let directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xff8c19);
       directionalLight.position.set(0,0,1);
       scene.add(directionalLight);

       scene = new THREE.Scene();
       camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60,window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
       camera.position.z = 1;
       camera.rotation.x = 1.16;
       camera.rotation.y = -0.12;
       camera.rotation.z = 0.27;

       let cloudParticles = [];
       cloudParticles.push(cloud);
           for(let p=0; p<50; p++) {
         let cloud = new THREE.Mesh(cloudGeo, cloudMaterial);
         cloud.position.set(
           Math.random()*800 -400,
           500,
           Math.random()*500-500
         );
         cloud.rotation.x = 1.16;
         cloud.rotation.y = -0.12;
         cloud.rotation.z = Math.random()*2*Math.PI;
         cloud.material.opacity = 0.55;
         cloudParticles.push(cloud);
         scene.add(cloud);
       }

           let cloudParticles = [];

       cloudParticles.push(cloud);

       function render() {
          cloudParticles.forEach(p => {
             p.rotation.z -=0.001;
          });
          let directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xff8c19);
       directionalLight.position.set(0,0,1);
       scene.add(directionalLight);

             let orangeLight = new THREE.PointLight(0xcc6600,50,450,1.7);
       orangeLight.position.set(200,300,100);
       scene.add(orangeLight);
       let redLight = new THREE.PointLight(0xd8547e,50,450,1.7);
       redLight.position.set(100,300,100);
       scene.add(redLight);
       let blueLight = new THREE.PointLight(0x3677ac,50,450,1.7);
       blueLight.position.set(300,300,200);
       scene.add(blueLight);

             const bloomEffect = new POSTPROCESSING.BloomEffect({
             blendFunction: POSTPROCESSING.BlendFunction.COLOR_DODGE,
             kernelSize: POSTPROCESSING.KernelSize.SMALL,
             useLuminanceFilter: true,
             luminanceThreshold: 0.3,
             luminanceSmoothing: 0.75
           });
       bloomEffect.blendMode.opacity.value = 1.5;

             loader.load("stars.jpg", function(texture){
         const textureEffect = new POSTPROCESSING.TextureEffect({
           blendFunction: POSTPROCESSING.BlendFunction.COLOR_DODGE,
           texture: texture
         });
         textureEffect.blendMode.opacity.value = 0.2;
           window.addEventListener("resize", onWindowResize, false);
           function onWindowResize() {
               camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
               camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
               renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
             }

             // animation loop
       function update() {

         // add some rotation to the system
         particleSystem.rotation.y += 0.01;

         var pCount = particleCount;
         while (pCount--) {

           // get the particle
           var particle =
             particles.vertices[pCount];

           // check if we need to reset
           if (particle.position.y < -200) {
             particle.position.y = 200;
             particle.velocity.y = 0;
           }

           // update the velocity with
           // a splat of randomniz
           particle.velocity.y -= Math.random() * .1;

           // and the position
           particle.position.addSelf(
             particle.velocity);
         }

         // flag to the particle system
         // that we've changed its vertices.
         particleSystem.
           geometry.
           __dirtyVertices = true;
         // draw
         draw.scene, draw.camera
         // set up the next call
         requestAnimFrame(update);

         // set up the next call

         requestAnimFrame(update);
       }
    </script>
  </body>
  <script>
    const url = "./style.css";
    document.head.innerHTML += `<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href=${url}>`;
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: What's this `.onload: scene;`? Doesn't look like valid js.

Comment: also are you using the correct three.js version. Unfortunately versions are not necessarily compatible with previous versions, ans so is code written for these versions

Comment: `.onload scene;` isn't useful - got it is there a reason I can't get any of this to load? because so far none of it seems to load - at all in fact.

Comment: Remove the `<script>...</script>` from around `<script src="three.min.js"></script>`. Also, remove that last `<script>` that's trying to change `document.head`. What even is the point of that?